# Mockmvc put method always return 204 status

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, spring-data-rest

I am writing test cases for my spring data rest repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "teams", path = "teams")
public interface TeamRepo extends JpaRepository<Team, Long> {}
```

Everything is ok but when i update invalid resource with put method, mockmvc always return status 204.
The code is as follow:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void updateInvalidResourceFail_thenReturn400() throws Exception {
    final Team resource = createNewResource();
    invalidate(resource); // Some properties violate uniqueness constraints
    final String resourceAsString = marshaller.encode(resource);
    mvc.perform(
            put("/api/teams/1")
                    .contentType(marshaller.getMime())
                    .content(resourceAsString)
    ).andExpect(status().isBadRequest()).andDo(print());

    TestTransaction.flagForCommit();
    TestTransaction.end();
}
```

mockmvc:

```
protected MockMvc mvc;
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    mvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
}
```

error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :400
Actual   :204
```

However, PostMan return the right result with same invalid data:

```
{
"status": "BAD_REQUEST",
"instant": "2018-06-13T06:16:20.975Z",
"message": "Database error, Constraint  Violation",
"debug": "could not execute statement"
}
```

When i change the expect status to 204,

```
.andExpect(status().isNoContent()).andDo(print());
```

i get the expected exception：

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

cause:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: #23000
```

It look like that mockmvc always return 204. Where am I going wrong?

## Edit

Entity Team:

```
@Entity
@ToString
@DynamicUpdate
@DynamicInsert
@Table(name = "bus_team", schema = "test", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
            "name"
    })
})
public class Team{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String division;
    // ... getter, setter
 }
```

method invalidate(Team team):

```
void invalidate(Team team){
    team.setName("name already exists");
}
```

Comment: what kind of constraint are you expecting to be violated?  How are you invalidating the data?

Comment: @robjwilkins, thanks  for reply. I just set the team's name with an existing value. You can read my edited question for more detials.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two potential reasons why this behaviour is happening.

The first is that you're doing a PUT, and rather than trying to create a new object in the database it is simply updating the existing object with amended values.  Therefore the unique constraint is not being violated, since the previous value is just over-written with the new one.

The second possible cause, is when you run the test with mockmvc it will use an in-memory data source.  When you run the test with Postman, it presumably uses a different data source (depending on your config).  So the mockmvc tests will start with a fresh database, containing different data from your Postman test database.  Therefore the test will possibly not trigger the constraint violation, unless you ensure there is the right data already in the in-memory database used by the mockmvc test.  Hopefully this makes sense!  Are you sure that the in-memory datasource contains the data needed to trigger the integrity constraint you expect?